# Extract names from another table

Tags: mysql, select

I have data in two tables. One has order details, the other has product details. The `order_details` table references the `product` table via the `product_id` column. The `product` table has columns `product_id` and `product_name`.

I count sales per product ID like this:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM order_details
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

and get output like this:

```
product_id  
123         2500
421         1700
111         1040
```

Now I want to have the names from the `product` table instead of the IDs:

```
apples  2500
banana  1700
pear    1040
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (possibly) most efficient way, first group, then join:

```
SELECT
    product_name, c
FROM
    (
      SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS c
      FROM order_details
      GROUP BY product_id
    ) AS counts
    /* The trick is now to JOIN this virtual table with your product table */
    JOIN product p ON p.product_id = counts.product_id
ORDER BY 
    c DESC ;
```

You can check that it works in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1030a5/3/0) (scaled by a 10 factor).

This SQL is very close to standard, so it should work not only with MySQL, but with most SQL databases (I've tested it with MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite).

---

Most contemporary databases will probably execute the following query with the same efficiency, provided that `NOT NULL` and `REFERENCES` are in place (and you type a bit less, and probably make it easier to understand):

```
SELECT 
    p.product_name, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM 
    order_details od
    JOIN product p ON p.product_id = od.product_id
GROUP BY 
    p.product_id
ORDER BY 
    count(*) DESC ;
```

Or, without using aliases:

```
SELECT 
    product.product_name, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM 
    order_details
    JOIN product ON product.product_id = order_details.product_id
GROUP BY 
    product.product_id
ORDER BY 
    count(*) DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ...I used the second version...it works but I don't understand exactly why :) 

select product_name ...but where is written from table "product"? 
:)

Comment: The `product` table is written in the `FROM` clause, where you do two things: add aliases (`p` is a shortcut or an alias for `product` and `od` is an alias for `order_details`) so that you write a bit less, and `JOIN` both tables, which the condition that the `product_id` must be the same on both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provided product table information,i just simulated a table as like below and please find the query

```
create table product_tab(product_id number(3),product_name varchar2(10))

create table order_details(product_id number(3),order_amount number(5))

SELECT a.product_name,b.product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM product_tab a,order_details b
where a.product_id=b.product_id
GROUP BY b.product_id,a.product_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

output:

```
apples  123 11
banana  421 8
pear    111 3
```